# how to combine ips to increase server bandwidth?

Tags: linux-networking

I have several ips. Each of them is limited to 2MB/s by the network provider. How can I assign multiple ips to one server to increase my server's outgoing bandwidth? My server runs CentOS 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Load balance your incoming requests such that half of the requests hit one IP and half hit the other.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain more about how to load balance? I only have one machine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS